# ViciDial: MyISAM Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Tags: mariadb, myisam

I have installed MariaDB in a Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to run some scripts that the main solution provides (ViciDial). When I try to execute the Sql file, it gives an error in the following CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE www_phrases (
phrase_id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
phrase_text VARCHAR(10000) default '',
php_filename VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
php_directory VARCHAR(255) default '',
source VARCHAR(20) default '',
insert_date DATETIME,
index (phrase_text)
) ENGINE=MyISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The error is:

```
ERROR 1071 (42000) at line 3348: Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
```

MariaDB status:

```
MariaDB [DialerDB]> status;
-------------- 
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.38-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Connection id:          53 
Current database:       DialerDB 
Current user:           root@localhost 
SSL:                    Not in use 
Current pager:          stdout 
Using outfile:          '' 
Using delimiter:        ; 
Server:                 MariaDB 
Server version:   10.0.38-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Ubuntu 16.04 
Protocol version:       10 
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket 
Server characterset:    utf8mb4 
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4 
Client characterset:    utf8mb4 
Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb4 
UNIX socket:  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 
Uptime:                 1 hour 15 min 49 sec
```

As far as I understand the limit in MyISAM is 1000, and in newer versions is around 3200, so if the varchar is 10000 this is an error, correct?
But this software is installed correctly if done via installer (an ISO image) and the DB tables are the same...so there must be some config limiting my MariaDB to do this.

Any idea?

Comment: Update: Executed the SQL query via "mysql -p" and it worked without issues...so guess console mode has something different. By console I mean:mysql -uroot -p DialerDB <  MySQL_AST_CREATE_tables.sql

Comment: -p just means "with password authentication" and will then ask for the password if you didn't provide one on the CLI. But if your error happened on "line 3348", I suspect the error occurred during a CLI input as well unless you were using something like phpMyAdmin or mysql workbench. So where did you see this error? And was the code you provided on "line 3348" of the file being imported or of a query in a field in a web interface?

Answer (score 0):

If that column has "text" in it, suggest looking into a `FULLTEXT` index; it will search for words quite efficiently.

A compilation of the limits is [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits); 10K won't work for a simple index.

(Meanwhile, you should move from MyISAM to InnoDB.)